# Ext.js Dynamically update GridPanel row record

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs, dynamic

I am working on how to dynamically update a GridPanel record in in ext.js using native JavaScript ofcourse. So, I check the Ext.data.Store objects many properties and methods and there does not seem to be an update method. However, there is a remove, and an add method. Is the only way to update the record in the grid, to first remove the existing copy of it and then add the updated record to the GridPanel as if it were new?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the record first, for example:

```
grid.getStore().getAt(0).set({yourFieldName:'new value'});
```

There's no need to remove the record, update it and add it back, just update it in-place as above.